# How to skip a ticklabel on a tkzAxe?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, plot, tkz-collection

The picture below shows my problem: I want to skip the "2" on the x_2-axis. How can I do that?

[image: example]

Here's the corresponding code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{myDots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{10pt}{10pt}}%
{
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{.5pt}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=5]
        \tkzAxeX[label=$x_1$]
        \tkzAxeY[label=$x_2$,orig=false]

        % points
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){x1}   
        \tkzDefPoint(0,3){x2}
        \tkzDefPoint(3,3){x3}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,0){x4}

        {
            \tkzSetUpPoint[size=10,fill=black]
            \tkzDrawPoints(x1,x2,x3,x4)
        }

        % decision space
        \tkzDrawSegments(x2,x3 x4,x3)
        \tkzFillPolygon[pattern=myDots](x1,x2,x3,x4)
        \tkzDefPoint(1.,1.75){X}  
        \tkzLabelPoint(X){$\mathcal{X}$}

        % D-set 
        \tkzDefPoint(0,1.75){p1}
        \tkzLabelPoint[right](p1){$x'$}
        \tkzDefPoint(-1.5,2.25){p2}
        \tkzDefPoint(-0.75,3.75){p3}

        \tkzDrawSegments(p2,p1 p1,p3)

        \tkzDefPoint(-1,3){d1}
        \tkzLabelPoint[left](d1){$\mathcal{D}_{x'}$}
        \tkzFillPolygon[pattern=dots](p1,p2,p3) 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would draw a white rectangle over label '2' before plotting the shaded area on the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a solution, using `\tkzDrawY` and `\tkzLabelPoint` command.

**Note** one can use `\tkzDefPoint`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{myDots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{10pt}{10pt}}%
{
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{.5pt}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=5]
        \tkzAxeX[label=$x_1$]
        \tkzDrawY[label=$x_2$]
        \foreach \y in {1,...,5} {% 
        \ifnum \y=2
        %\tkzLabelPoint[right=1pt](0,\y){\y} 
        \else
        \tkzLabelPoint[left=1pt](0,\y){\y}
        \fi}

        % points
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){x1}   
        \tkzDefPoint(0,3){x2}
        \tkzDefPoint(3,3){x3}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,0){x4}

        {
            \tkzSetUpPoint[size=10,fill=black]
            \tkzDrawPoints(x1,x2,x3,x4)
        }

        % decision space
        \tkzDrawSegments(x2,x3 x4,x3)
        \tkzFillPolygon[pattern=myDots](x1,x2,x3,x4)
        \tkzDefPoint(1.,1.75){X}  
        \tkzLabelPoint(X){$\mathcal{X}$}

        % D-set 
        \tkzDefPoint(0,1.75){p1}
        \tkzLabelPoint[right](p1){$x'$}
        \tkzDefPoint(-1.5,2.25){p2}
        \tkzDefPoint(-0.75,3.75){p3}

        \tkzDrawSegments(p2,p1 p1,p3)

        \tkzDefPoint(-1,3){d1}
        \tkzLabelPoint[left](d1){$\mathcal{D}_{x'}$}
        \tkzFillPolygon[pattern=dots](p1,p2,p3) 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```